# Integrating to a mid level E2 account

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to integrate to a section of an E2 account - a business unit plus any business units below that. I do not want to deal with any of the business units above it, or on other branches of the hierarchy.

Can I just have an API user defined at the top level of MY business unit and do QueryAllAccounts as if I were working at the top level, or is it more involved than that?

The areas of interest are - retrieving email names and folders, retrieving results, sending email.

thanks in advance if you can offer any insights...

Comment: I realize that this is an ExactTarget question, but could you provide some additional detail? We don't get many ET questions here (though someone should be able to answer it).

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar situation, and what I learned was that QueryAllAccounts will indeed get you all the accounts in the Enterprise.  BUT, there is some good news... its restricted by permissions on the API user, so you should be able to create a restricted API user to do what you're looking for.

Hope this helps!